# Clear Search Result in EntityFrameWork

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, datagrid

I have a database called Employee and I am using entity framework version 6.1.3. 
In my wpf application, I have button called Search, one textbox( searchField) for search field and a datagrid ( employeedatagrid)

When i enter input in search field, it gives expected output in datagrid view but after that when i enter again different input in searchfield,  it just prints the new data just below the previous data. What I want is; When i enter different search field , then If there is already data in datagrid, I want to remove those old data from datagrid and prints only the new data. 
Below is my C# Code

```
private void Search_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.employeeDataGrid.ItemsSource = null;
        this.employeeDataGrid.Items.Clear();
        var text = SearchField.Text;
        var query = employeeModel.Employees.Where(x => x.Country == text).Select(y => y);
        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            employeeDataGrid.ItemsSource = employeeModel.Employees.Local;
        }
    }
```

Can anyone point out, what I am missing here ?
thanks.

Comment: This issue should have nothing to do with EntityFramework. What does your xaml structure look like? Also, I suggest declaring a collection that you can bind your ItemsSource attribute to.

Comment: my xaml structure is, I have created data source object from existing database and just drag and drop of that data source  in the wpf form in a detail view mode.

Comment: That sounds like an ancient technique of working with data. Could you verify if you can successfully clear items?? For example, comment all code after the clear statement (this.employeeDataGrid.Items.Clear();) and see if the old data has been successfully cleared from the DataGrid View

Comment: yes if i use that code in separate button, it clears old data from the datagrid but again when i search new query, the result comes both old data query and new data...This seems really strange.

Comment: Forget about the UI now, put a debug point at the end of the Search_Click function and check the ItemsSource collection; does it have duplicate data (or both old and new query result)?

Comment: I fixed by checking the MSDN documentation. Instead of creating foreach loop, I just used employeeDataGrid.ItemsSource = query.ToList();